# Make backups of Dropbox folder every week

Tags: windows, backup, script, dropbox

I have a Dropbox folder which is shared by couple of users. I would like to make a backup of this folder that will occur every week and store this backup on another hard drive.

I can simply copy the entire folder each time  and this will be the backup, but I would like to copy only the files that have been changed or created during that week.

I thought of creating a batch script that will check each file in the Dropbox folder recursively and see its modified date.  If that date is later then a given one (current backup date) it will copy the file to a folder named `BackUP[Date]`.

Do you think this solution is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple `xcopy` does the trick:

```
echo off
if exist "C:\Backup" goto GO
goto ERR

:GO
xcopy "C:\Cypress\*.*" "C:\Backup\*.*" /m/e/y
echo/
echo ** Copy complete! **
echo/
pause

:ERR
echo/
echo ** ERROR - files cannot be copied! **
echo/
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It appers to me to be overkill to write a batch script for you. You can do this easily via a GUI-application, like [Comodo Backup](http://backup.comodo.com/backup-features.php#free-online-data-backup-expert-help).

It can even backup to FTP drives:

> Backup to anywhere Network drive, external drive, FTP, DVD/CD, ISO,
>   zip, online storage - you name it, Comodo Backup can copy to it!

Comment: Im on windows. its local folder that is shared by dropbox and used by others. i want to have a backup on a different external hardisk.

Comment: I edited my answer :)

Comment: Id rather do it on batch script so i could manage it by myself without 3rd party tool.. thanks for the commodo backup link. but i dont like commercial apps, if i can do it myself.

Comment: this work: 
echo off
if exist "C:\Backup" goto GO
goto ERR

:GO
xcopy "C:\Cypress\*.*" "C:\Backup\*.*" /m/e/y
echo/
echo ** Copy complete! **
echo/
pause


:ERR
echo/
echo ** ERROR - files cannot be copied! **
echo/
pause

Comment: @ilansch Answer your own question please with that script. It doesn't work in comments, since everything is in one line,

Comment: yes since im a noob i was not able to answer my questions only after 7 hours since publish :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Microsoft's free [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) utility to do this. Its documentation describes how to run it from the command-line, which means it can be can be started from a batch script to run all or specific "jobs". There's also instructions for setting it up as a scheduled task that will run it automatically at set times every day, week, month, etc. A log file is produced which can be consulted to verify its processing and help trouble-shoot any issues. All-in-all a decent program, although it's no speed-demon, IMHO.